# Flink 1.4.0 ClassDefNotFoundError ... S3ErrorResponseHandler

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Working on setting up a local test of Flink 1.4.0 that writes to s3 and I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.flink.fs.s3presto.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3ErrorResponseHandler
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3presto.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:363)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3presto.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:542)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3presto.shaded.com.facebook.presto.hive.PrestoS3FileSystem.createAmazonS3Client(PrestoS3FileSystem.java:639)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3presto.shaded.com.facebook.presto.hive.PrestoS3FileSystem.initialize(PrestoS3FileSystem.java:212)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3presto.S3FileSystemFactory.create(S3FileSystemFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.getUnguardedFileSystem(FileSystem.java:397)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:320)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:293)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FsCheckpointStreamFactory.<init>(FsCheckpointStreamFactory.java:99)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FsStateBackend.createStreamFactory(FsStateBackend.java:277)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.createCheckpointStreamFactory(StreamTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:247)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeOperators(StreamTask.java:694)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeState(StreamTask.java:682)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:253)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:718)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Following the [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/ops/deployment/aws.html#shaded-hadooppresto-s3-file-systems-recommended) here I added the `flink-s3-fs-presto-1.4.0.jar` from `opt/` to `lib/` so I'm not exactly sure why I'm getting this error. Any help would be appreciated let me know if I can add additional information.

Here is some more information about my system and process:

I start the local job manager:

```
[flink-1.4.0] ./bin/start-local.sh                                                                                                                                                               
Warning: this file is deprecated and will be removed in 1.5.
Starting cluster.
Starting jobmanager daemon on host MBP0535.local.
Starting taskmanager daemon on host MBP0535.local.
```

OS information:

```
[flink-1.4.0] system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType                                                                                                                                                  
Software:

    System Software Overview:

      System Version: macOS 10.13.2 (17C205)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 17.3.0
      Boot Volume: Macintosh HD
```

Try to run jar:

```
[flink-1.4.0] ./bin/flink run streaming.jar
```

I'm actually having trouble reproducing the error. Here is the task manager log:

```
2018-01-18 10:17:07,668 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -  Starting TaskManager (Version: 1.4.0, Rev:3a9d9f2, Date:06.12.2017 @ 11:08:40 UTC)
2018-01-18 10:17:07,668 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -  OS current user: k
2018-01-18 10:17:08,002 WARN  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader                       - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2018-01-18 10:17:08,084 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -  Current Hadoop/Kerberos user: k
2018-01-18 10:17:08,084 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -  JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM - Oracle Corporation - 1.8/25.152-b16
2018-01-18 10:17:08,084 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -  Maximum heap size: 1024 MiBytes
2018-01-18 10:17:08,084 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -  JAVA_HOME: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home
2018-01-18 10:17:08,087 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -  Hadoop version: 2.8.1
2018-01-18 10:17:08,087 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -  JVM Options:
2018-01-18 10:17:08,087 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     -XX:+UseG1GC
2018-01-18 10:17:08,087 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     -Xms1024M
2018-01-18 10:17:08,087 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     -Xmx1024M
2018-01-18 10:17:08,087 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=8388607T
2018-01-18 10:17:08,087 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     -Dlog.file=/Users/k/flink-1.4.0/log/flink-k-taskmanager-0-MBP0535.local.log
2018-01-18 10:17:08,087 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/Users/k/flink-1.4.0/conf/log4j.properties
2018-01-18 10:17:08,087 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:/Users/k/flink-1.4.0/conf/logback.xml
2018-01-18 10:17:08,087 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -  Program Arguments:
2018-01-18 10:17:08,088 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     --configDir
2018-01-18 10:17:08,088 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     /Users/k/flink-1.4.0/conf
2018-01-18 10:17:08,088 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -  Classpath: /Users/k/flink-1.4.0/lib/flink-python_2.11-1.4.0.jar:/Users/k/flink-1.4.0/lib/flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.4.0.jar:/Users/k/flink-1.4.0/lib/flink-shaded-hadoop2-uber-1.4.0.jar:/Users/k/flink-1.4.0/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/Users/k/flink-1.4.0/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar:/Users/k/flink-1.4.0/lib/flink-dist_2.11-1.4.0.jar:::
2018-01-18 10:17:08,089 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2018-01-18 10:17:08,094 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Maximum number of open file descriptors is 10240
2018-01-18 10:17:08,117 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Loading configuration from /Users/k/flink-1.4.0/conf
2018-01-18 10:17:08,119 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: classloader.resolve-order, parent-first
2018-01-18 10:17:08,119 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: classloader.parent-first-patterns, java.;org.apache.flink.;javax.annotation;org.slf4j;org.apache.log4j;org.apache.logging.log4j;ch.qos.logback;com.mapr.;org.apache.
2018-01-18 10:17:08,120 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: s3.access-key, XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
2018-01-18 10:17:08,120 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: s3.secret-key, YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
2018-01-18 10:17:08,120 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.address, localhost
2018-01-18 10:17:08,120 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.port, 6123
2018-01-18 10:17:08,120 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.heap.mb, 1024
2018-01-18 10:17:08,120 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.heap.mb, 1024
2018-01-18 10:17:08,120 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots, 1
2018-01-18 10:17:08,121 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.memory.preallocate, false
2018-01-18 10:17:08,121 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: parallelism.default, 1
2018-01-18 10:17:08,121 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: web.port, 8082
2018-01-18 10:17:08,199 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.security.modules.HadoopModule        - Hadoop user set to k (auth:SIMPLE)
2018-01-18 10:17:08,289 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.util.LeaderRetrievalUtils            - Trying to select the network interface and address to use by connecting to the leading JobManager.
2018-01-18 10:17:08,289 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.util.LeaderRetrievalUtils            - TaskManager will try to connect for 10000 milliseconds before falling back to heuristics
2018-01-18 10:17:08,291 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.net.ConnectionUtils                  - Retrieved new target address localhost/127.0.0.1:6123.
2018-01-18 10:17:08,472 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - TaskManager will use hostname/address 'MBP0535.local' (10.1.11.139) for communication.
2018-01-18 10:17:08,482 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Starting TaskManager
2018-01-18 10:17:08,482 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Starting TaskManager actor system at MBP0535.local:54024.
2018-01-18 10:17:08,484 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Trying to start actor system at mbp0535.local:54024
2018-01-18 10:17:08,898 INFO  akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger                                  - Slf4jLogger started
2018-01-18 10:17:08,960 INFO  akka.remote.Remoting                                          - Starting remoting
2018-01-18 10:17:09,087 INFO  akka.remote.Remoting                                          - Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://flink@mbp0535.local:54024]
2018-01-18 10:17:09,097 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Actor system started at akka.tcp://flink@mbp0535.local:54024
2018-01-18 10:17:09,105 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.metrics.MetricRegistryImpl           - No metrics reporter configured, no metrics will be exposed/reported.
2018-01-18 10:17:09,111 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Starting TaskManager actor
2018-01-18 10:17:09,115 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyConfig         - NettyConfig [server address: MBP0535.local/10.1.11.139, server port: 0, ssl enabled: false, memory segment size (bytes): 32768, transport type: NIO, number of server threads: 1 (manual), number of client threads: 1 (manual), server connect backlog: 0 (use Netty's default), client connect timeout (sec): 120, send/receive buffer size (bytes): 0 (use Netty's default)]
2018-01-18 10:17:09,118 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerConfiguration  - Messages have a max timeout of 10000 ms
2018-01-18 10:17:09,122 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerServices     - Temporary file directory '/var/folders/sw/jcdfbbc15td51f3635hvt77w0000gp/T': total 465 GB, usable 333 GB (71.61% usable)
2018-01-18 10:17:09,236 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.buffer.NetworkBufferPool  - Allocated 101 MB for network buffer pool (number of memory segments: 3255, bytes per segment: 32768).
2018-01-18 10:17:09,323 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.query.QueryableStateUtils            - Could not load Queryable State Client Proxy. Probable reason: flink-queryable-state-runtime is not in the classpath. Please put the corresponding jar from the opt to the lib folder.
2018-01-18 10:17:09,324 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.query.QueryableStateUtils            - Could not load Queryable State Server. Probable reason: flink-queryable-state-runtime is not in the classpath. Please put the corresponding jar from the opt to the lib folder.
2018-01-18 10:17:09,324 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.NetworkEnvironment        - Starting the network environment and its components.
2018-01-18 10:17:09,353 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyClient         - Successful initialization (took 23 ms).
2018-01-18 10:17:09,378 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyServer         - Successful initialization (took 25 ms). Listening on SocketAddress /10.1.11.139:54026.
2018-01-18 10:17:09,381 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManagerLocation      - No hostname could be resolved for the IP address 10.1.11.139, using IP address as host name. Local input split assignment (such as for HDFS files) may be impacted.
2018-01-18 10:17:09,431 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerServices     - Limiting managed memory to 0.7 of the currently free heap space (640 MB), memory will be allocated lazily.
2018-01-18 10:17:09,437 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.disk.iomanager.IOManager          - I/O manager uses directory /var/folders/sw/jcdfbbc15td51f3635hvt77w0000gp/T/flink-io-186cf8c8-5a0d-44cc-9d78-e81c943b0b9f for spill files.
2018-01-18 10:17:09,439 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.filecache.FileCache                  - User file cache uses directory /var/folders/sw/jcdfbbc15td51f3635hvt77w0000gp/T/flink-dist-cache-a9a568cd-c7cd-45c6-abbe-08912d051583
2018-01-18 10:17:09,509 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.filecache.FileCache                  - User file cache uses directory /var/folders/sw/jcdfbbc15td51f3635hvt77w0000gp/T/flink-dist-cache-bd3cc98c-cebb-4569-98d3-5357393d8c5b
2018-01-18 10:17:09,516 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Starting TaskManager actor at akka://flink/user/taskmanager#1044592356.
2018-01-18 10:17:09,516 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - TaskManager data connection information: 97b3a934f84ba25e20aae8a91a40e336 @ 10.1.11.139 (dataPort=54026)
2018-01-18 10:17:09,516 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - TaskManager has 1 task slot(s).
2018-01-18 10:17:09,518 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Memory usage stats: [HEAP: 112/1024/1024 MB, NON HEAP: 35/36/-1 MB (used/committed/max)]
2018-01-18 10:17:09,522 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Trying to register at JobManager akka.tcp://flink@localhost:6123/user/jobmanager (attempt 1, timeout: 500 milliseconds)
2018-01-18 10:17:09,692 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Successful registration at JobManager (akka.tcp://flink@localhost:6123/user/jobmanager), starting network stack and library cache.
2018-01-18 10:17:09,696 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Determined BLOB server address to be localhost/127.0.0.1:54025. Starting BLOB cache.
2018-01-18 10:17:09,699 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.PermanentBlobCache              - Created BLOB cache storage directory /var/folders/sw/jcdfbbc15td51f3635hvt77w0000gp/T/blobStore-77287aab-5128-4363-842c-1a124114fd91
2018-01-18 10:17:09,702 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.TransientBlobCache              - Created BLOB cache storage directory /var/folders/sw/jcdfbbc15td51f3635hvt77w0000gp/T/blobStore-c9f62e97-bf53-4fc4-9e4a-1958706e78ec
2018-01-18 10:26:25,993 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Received task Source: Kafka -> Sink: S3 (1/1)
2018-01-18 10:26:25,993 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Source: Kafka -> Sink: S3 (1/1) (95b54853308d69fbb84ee308508bf397) switched from CREATED to DEPLOYING.
2018-01-18 10:26:25,994 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Creating FileSystem stream leak safety net for task Source: Kafka -> Sink: S3 (1/1) (95b54853308d69fbb84ee308508bf397) [DEPLOYING]
2018-01-18 10:26:25,996 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Loading JAR files for task Source: Kafka -> Sink: S3 (1/1) (95b54853308d69fbb84ee308508bf397) [DEPLOYING].
2018-01-18 10:26:25,998 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobClient                      - Downloading 34e7c81bd4a0050e7809a1343af0c7cb/p-4eaec529eb247f30ef2d3ddc2308e029e625de33-93fe90509266a50ffadce2131cedc514 from localhost/127.0.0.1:54025
2018-01-18 10:26:26,238 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Registering task at network: Source: Kafka -> Sink: S3 (1/1) (95b54853308d69fbb84ee308508bf397) [DEPLOYING].
2018-01-18 10:26:26,240 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Source: Kafka -> Sink: S3 (1/1) (95b54853308d69fbb84ee308508bf397) switched from DEPLOYING to RUNNING.
2018-01-18 10:26:26,249 INFO  org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask           - Using user-defined state backend: File State Backend @ s3://stream-data/checkpoints.
2018-01-18 10:26:26,522 INFO  org.apache.flink.fs.s3hadoop.shaded.org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader  - Skipping native-hadoop library for flink-s3-fs-hadoop's relocated Hadoop... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2018-01-18 10:26:29,041 ERROR org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.bucketing.BucketingSink  - Error while creating FileSystem when initializing the state of the BucketingSink.
java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: s3
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.bucketing.BucketingSink.createHadoopFileSystem(BucketingSink.java:1196)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.bucketing.BucketingSink.initFileSystem(BucketingSink.java:411)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.bucketing.BucketingSink.initializeState(BucketingSink.java:355)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.tryRestoreFunction(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:178)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.restoreFunctionState(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:160)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:96)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:259)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeOperators(StreamTask.java:694)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeState(StreamTask.java:682)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:253)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:718)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-01-18 10:26:29,048 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Source: Kafka -> Sink: S3 (1/1) (95b54853308d69fbb84ee308508bf397) switched from RUNNING to FAILED.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while creating FileSystem when initializing the state of the BucketingSink.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.bucketing.BucketingSink.initializeState(BucketingSink.java:358)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.tryRestoreFunction(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:178)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.restoreFunctionState(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:160)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:96)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:259)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeOperators(StreamTask.java:694)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeState(StreamTask.java:682)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:253)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:718)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: s3
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.bucketing.BucketingSink.createHadoopFileSystem(BucketingSink.java:1196)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.bucketing.BucketingSink.initFileSystem(BucketingSink.java:411)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.bucketing.BucketingSink.initializeState(BucketingSink.java:355)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: There is a thread on the flink mailing list about this issue which would benefit greatly from more information: https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/46d7dcd5e37f4e69c1fec0d34634d96ea4c79fb1506ed3a35af830e4@%3Cuser.flink.apache.org%3E

Comment: Can you post a bit more information, like OS, exact JVM version, and ideally the classpath (from the Flink logs)?

Comment: @StephanEwen I added some more context let me know if I can add more...

Comment: @StephanEwen Added start of task manager logs which shows java version, classpath etc...

Comment: Just curious what you have for `classloader.resolve-order:` in your `conf/flink-conf.yaml` file.

Comment: Ken has a good point, can you check what happens if you set the the "classloader.resolve-order: parent-first" in your configuration. Alternatively, make sure that the flink-s3-fs-presto-1.4.0.jar is not par of your job's fat jar.